# how to add multible bytes together?

Tags: java, byte, arrays

I'm trying to write a ROM file patcher and I came to this in the documentation:

```
The next three bytes are the place in the destination file
(the file to be patched) where a change is to be made.

The two bytes following that are the length of the amount
of data to be changed.
```

How would I turn those three and two bytes into a single number in java properly?

Comment: Read the next byte, OR it with the result (your temp var), then shift the result by 8 bits left, repeat.

Comment: @mojuba - Write this as one of the proposed answers to the question so it can be accepted by William if he finds it to answer the question.

Comment: @mojuba Is that a normal OR or a bitwise OR? also I would shift it by coding "<< 8" right?

Comment: AndyPerfect: let someone write it in proper Java, I don't know Java...

Comment: William, of course it's bitwise OR, and yes, it's << 8

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention, it also depends on the "endianness" of the data. The documentation should mention it too, i.e. is the first byte in a series the highest one or the lowest one?

Comment: To bad SO doesn't give me a nice alert when comments are added, like it does with answers. :)P  Most of what I said was added as I was typing my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use a descendent of InputStream (byte vs char input).

The most important question to ask is if the data is stored in "little-endian" or "big-endian" fashion.  I'll assume little-endian (x86).  For the three-byte number:

```
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(...);

int byte1 = fs.read();
int byte2 = fs.read();
int byte3 = fs.read();
int data = (byte3 << 16) | (byte2 << 8) | byte1;
```

For little-endian, the first byte read is the least significant byte.

If you need big-endian, change the last line to:

```
int data = (byte1 << 16) | (byte2 << 8) | byte3;
```

Answer (score 2):

Strangely, I see a valid answer by **Joey**, which he deleted 10 minutes ago:

```
(byte1 << 16) + (byte2 << 8) + byte3
```

The only thing I have to add: do not convert bytes you read from InputStream to `byte` type (`InputStream#read` returns `int` value between 0 and 255). That'll turn `255` in `-1`, for example, and we don't need such side-effect.

So, it could look like

```
(in.read() << 16) + (in.read() << 8) + in.read()
```